# how to Set environment variable in hyperledger fabric chaincode container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

As my chaincode will get execute on each chaincode container, I want to set environment variable inside every chaincode container so that i can use this environment variable in my chaincode.

I don't have access to create a chaincode container. It will get created automatically at the time of chaincode instantiation (one docker container per peer). So that i don't have any control to set the environment variable inside chaincode containers.

I also think to update and commit the chaincode containers, but if there are more endorsing peers then this could take unnecessary delay. So according to my understanding, the best way is to set the environment variable at the time of container creation.

Please let me know how to solve above problem?

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to set an environment variable.  If there is some type of "configuration" setting you need to pass into chaincode then you should pass it as a parameter to the Init function and then save the value using PutState and retrieve it using GetState as required.

Comment: Thanks Gari. As i want the peer specific configurations inside chaincode, I am passing it in Invoke function and get my job done.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to set environment variables **before** running a container, use the `--env` argument for the `docker run` command:

   ```
   $ docker run --help
   ...
   -e, --env list                       Set environment variables
   --env-file list                  Read in a file of environment variables
   ```

   Use the `-e`, `--env`, and `--env-file` flags to set simple (non-array) environment variables in the container you’re running, or overwrite variables that are defined in the Dockerfile of the image you’re running. More info is [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e-env-env-file).

   ```
   docker run -e MYVAR1 --env MYVAR2=foo --env-file ./env.list ubuntu bash
   ```
2. If you want to set environment variables **after** running a container, Docker does not allow this currently. See these issues:

   https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8838

   https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7561

   > Right now Docker can't change the configuration of the container once it's created, and generally this is OK because it's trivial to create a new container